# How to set values to 2d array and access the values using arr[i][j] or arr[i,j] in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, exceljs

I need to copy few cells from one excel to another excel using node js.
Suppose i need to copy 3 cell values from 2 rows and assign to an array as below

**First row**

```
array[0,0] = A1 value

array[0,1] = B1 value

array[0,2] = C1 value
```

**Second Row**

```
array[1,0] = A2 value

array[1,1] = B2 value

array[1,2] = C2 value
```

After that i need to use the filled array and paste those values in another excel file in same location.That time i need to access  below array structure to paste into exact location.

**Excel 2**

```
A1 = array[0,0].value

B1 = array[1,0].value

etc...
```

It does not behave the same way as we do in c#. Please let me know the code required in javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, 2D array is nothing but array of array. That's exactly what you need to do in javascript to create one. For example :

```js
// you can use an Array construct as well.
let my_2d_array = [];

my_2d_array[0] = [];

my_2d_array[0][0] = 'some value';

console.log(my_2d_array[0][0]);
```

Similarly you can create an array of objects as well, based on your requirement.

Hope this helps !